# PineScript input.symbol does not cleared

Tags: pine-script

i tried to create an input box for symbol

```
asset_01    = input('', title="Asset 01", type=input.symbol)
```

which should allow the user to select the symbol accordingly. the problem is, once selected from the input screen, it cannot be cleared back to a blank ('') (which is the default value). is this pinescript limitation or I did something wrong? Any workaround?

Comment: Once entered, the input box doesn't accept empty values, but will always revert to the last non-empty value that you entered. Why would you want to make it empty again? What's the use case for this? Maybe there's another way to accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen this is for a custom screener script. One of the use case would be last week i was screening 20 stocks, but this week i only want to screen for 18. this is more of a ux concern. Anyway the Pinecoders mod already responded that its an issue they are not sure if it can be resolved. for now the solution they suggested is to reset everything to default so the whole list would be empty again

Comment: If you wish to screen stocks, you can do so via the "STOCK SCREENER" on the bottom left or make a single pinescript and ass alerts to all the scripts separately(not possible on a free account)